# Expect return HTML in ReactJS unit testing using JEST

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test this function

```
export const scoreText = score => {
  if (score < 1.0) {
    return <span style={{ color: '#fd7878' }}>{score}</span>;
  }

  if (score >= 1.0 && score <= 1.5) {
    return <span style={{ color: '#fd7878' }}>{score}</span>;
  }

  if ((score >= 1.51 && score <= 2.49) || (score >= 2.5 && score <= 3.0)) {
    return <span style={{ color: '#2fcc71' }}>{score}</span>;
  }

  return score;
};
```

This is my code now. How can I unit test to expect to return a HTML code?

```
describe('scoreText', () => {
  it('score less than 1.0', () => {
    expect(scoreText(0).toBeLessThan(1.0));
  });
  it('score not less than or equal to 1.0 greater than or equal to 1.5', () => {
    expect(scoreText(1.2).toBeLessThanOrEqual(1.5));
  });
  it('score not less than or equal to 1.5 greater than or equal to 2.49', () => {
    expect(scoreText(2.0).toBeLessThanOrEqual(2.49));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of wanting to see the entire `html` returned, I think you should go for using `snapshot` testing.

Generally, you would generate the html content & stored as file and you can check it if it's correct or not by using `toMatchSnapshot()` api:

```js
it('score less than 1.0', () => {
  expect(scoreText(0)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Then you would see the snapshot looks like:

```json
exports[`scoreText score less than 1.0 1`] = `
<span
  style={
    Object {
      "color": "#fd7878",
    }
  }
>
  0
</span>
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use toContain:

```
  expect(scoreText(1.2).toContain('<'));
```